# Is there a name for a "phantom" stroke handwritten by mistake?

Tags: terminology, handwriting

When handwriting the Chinese

## 休

it might be mistakenly written as

## 体

Afterwards, it has an additional "phantom" stroke which only exists because it's written incorrectly.  There's a number of "phantom" strokes when handwriting, e.g. the characters associated with:

- miswriting 冖 as 宀,
- miswriting 厂 as 广,
- miswriting 斤 as 斥,
- miswriting 礻 as 衤, and
- miswriting 戈 as 戋.

I'm wondering if there is a name for this "phantom" stroke, either in English or Chinese, and either in linguistics or in informal usage.

**Question**: Is there a name for a "phantom" stroke handwritten by mistake?

Comment: ”it's probably quite common to mistakenly write it“: I doubt it. Any source?

Comment: This seems unlikely to be a *common* mistake, though I suppose it might happen once in a long while.  Still, I can't really imagine myself making this mistake (and I make plenty).

Comment: Not really relevant but should-be-noted knowledge: when it comes to calligraphy, it's usual to add or remove some stroke (called 增笔/减笔) for aesthetic purposes. This [Zhihu post](https://www.zhihu.com/question/24901805/answer/29380313) offers a good explanation.

Comment: It seems [错别字](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23273) is related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called or [笔误](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%AC%94%E8%AF%AF) or [误笔](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%AF%AF%E7%AC%94) (handwriting mistake) or more colloquially "写错笔划" (write a wrong stroke)

写多笔划或是写少笔划都是笔误

俗语: "误将冯京作马凉" 就是典型的笔误引来的误会

Although 笔误 and 误笔 are interchangeable, there's also a term [口误](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8F%A3%E8%AF%AF) (slip of the tongue). Therefore, I prefer 笔误 over 误笔

Answer (score 1):

Seems there's no specified name for this "phantom-mistake".

and these Charactors have the name: 易错字.